# SMA for multiple items in the same column

Tags: r, moving-average

I'm trying to create SMA formula for multiple items in the same column. Here's an example of the data I'm working with.

```
 Person  Time Value
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A          1    14
 2 A          2    13
 3 A          3    17
 4 A          4     9
 5 A          5    20
 6 A          6     5
 7 B          1    17
 8 B          2    11
 9 B          3    18
10 B          4    10
11 B          5    10
12 B          6    20
13 C          1     5
14 C          2     5
15 C          3    11
16 C          4    12
17 C          5    12
18 C          6     9
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to create another column with the SMA formula for each person (A,B,C, etc.). In this case let's say SMA2. While it works for Person A, I can't get the formula to restart at Person B. Rather Person B's first SMA2 value has Person A's values with it.

Right now I've used this which does give me the SMA I want, just not restarted at each new person:

```
DataSet$SMA2<-SMA(DataSet$Value, 2)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
DataSet <- DataSet %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(sma2 = TTR::SMA(Value,2))
```

Still came up with this:

```html
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   Person [3]
   Person  Time Value  sma2
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A          1    14  NA  
 2 A          2    13  13.5
 3 A          3    17  15  
 4 A          4     9  13  
 5 A          5    20  14.5
 6 A          6     5  12.5
 7 B          1    17  11  
 8 B          2    11  14  
 9 B          3    18  14.5
10 B          4    10  14  
11 B          5    10  10  
12 B          6    20  15  
13 C          1     5  12.5
14 C          2     5   5  
15 C          3    11   8  
16 C          4    12  11.5
17 C          5    12  12  
18 C          6     9  10.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr, `group_by` person then use `mutate`. This will reset the calculations per person.

```
DataSet <- DataSet %>% 
  group_by(Person) %>% 
  mutate(sma2 = TTR::SMA(Value, 2))

# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   Person [3]
   Person  Time Value  sma2
   <chr>  <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 A          1    14  NA  
 2 A          2    13  13.5
 3 A          3    17  15  
 4 A          4     9  13  
 5 A          5    20  14.5
 6 A          6     5  12.5
 7 B          1    17  NA  
 8 B          2    11  14  
 9 B          3    18  14.5
10 B          4    10  14  
11 B          5    10  10  
12 B          6    20  15  
13 C          1     5  NA  
14 C          2     5   5  
15 C          3    11   8  
16 C          4    12  11.5
17 C          5    12  12  
18 C          6     9  10.5
```

Comment: That does work great, but how would I add that new column to the data frame. It still  shows up as the same amount of variables as there was before SMA2?

Comment: That sma2 actually didn't seem to work for some reason. Again, it worked for first variable, but not second or third. Why would this be? `DataSet <- DataSet %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(sma2 = TTR::SMA(Value,2))` It seems to still give me NA for Person A, but not Person B or C.

Comment: All set. Your original answer worked perfect after reloading the packages needed.Thank you for your response.